# how to make sure sms sent by my app is only received by a phone with my app installed

Tags: android, sms

I am writing an app that has a feature of sending and receiving SMS messages.  I would like SMS messages sent by my app be only received by another phone with my app installed and not reach phone's native SMS app.  The only solution I found so far is to set high priority to android:priority in Manifest file:

```
<receiver android:name=".SMSreceiver">
        <intent-filter android:priority="100">
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

and put this.abortBroadcast() statement in onReceive method to the class that extends BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class SMSreceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    private final String CODE = "myappcodeword";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
        String from = "";
        String str = "";
        String sms = "";

        if (bundle != null)
        {
            Object [] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
            for (int i = 0; i<msgs.length; i++)
            {
                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    from = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                }
                str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
            }

            if (str.startsWith(CODE)) // SMS starts with code word therefore was sent by my app
            {
                sms = str.substring(CODE.length()); // extract code word from actual sms message
                Intent SMSIntent = new Intent(context, SMSActivity.class);
                SMSIntent.putExtra("from", from);
                SMSIntent.putExtra("sms", sms);
                SMSIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(SMSIntent); // start new activity using sms info
                this.abortBroadcast();
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Since of course I don't want to block SMS not intended for my app, I thought of starting SMS messages sent by my app by some kind of key word.  My question is, is there a better solution than this?  (For example, user might theoretically actually send SMS to somebody containing key word on purpose no matter how random the key word is and my app would filter it out).  Also above code will not filter out the SMS sent by my app if the phone the SMS is sent to does not have my app installed.  Is there a way to find out first if the phone SMS is being send to has my app installed?  If the app is not installed then I would like the SMS not even show up on that phone.

Comment: Why SMS?  This sounds like a tough and maybe impossible task.  Why not build your own chat protocol?  Then you can have complete control

Comment: The app won't be text messaging app even though it sounds like that from description above :) The app will just share some data between users, so in the app user can click Share or something like that and the app will gather appropriate data and send it to another user.  Another user's app will extract data from message and display it in appropriate format.  I thought SMS is most appropriate for this but I could be totally wrong.  I am pretty new to android development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might want to look at GCM, allows you to target your application running on targeted devices based on your need.

[Google Cloud Messaging for Android](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot use SMS as a carrier for the scenario you describe. Remember that SMS is a store and forward service (in that respect similar to email) and the mobile operator might be storing the message for a long time (days is possible) if the recipient is not turned on or out of coverage (at some point it will be discarded, but that is up till the operator to decide).